Supercapacitor Balancer Circuit
I’m working on a balancer circuit that’s part of a supercapacitor charging system, but I’m having trouble understanding how it works. Specifically, I’m confused by how the values of V1-VA and VE-SCAP change when I adjust V1. This wasn't something I expected.
For example, when V1 = 3V, V1-VA = 1.1V, but when V1 = 6V, V1-VA increases to 1.45V. I’m using the following approach to analyze the circuit:
VB = (V1-VA) * (475) / (475 + 49.9)
SCAP = VB - VBE(Q12) + VD1
So for V1 = 6V, I calculated:
VB = (6 - 1.45) * 475 / (475 + 49.9) = 3.62V
SCAP = 3.62V - 0.7V - 0.7V = 2.2V
However, the LTspice simulation shows SCAP as 3V, evenly split, and my approach doesn’t seem to match that result.


Could anyone offer advice or point out where I might be going wrong?
PS: I’m having trouble understanding how this circuit is supposed to balance the capacitors when they have different tolerances. For example, if one has a voltage rating of 2.7V and another has a rating of 2.5V, how does it maintain balance?

Should Q11 be PNP, emitter at top?

@Simon Fitch I have been told that this design works, and this circuitry is duplicated for charging an array of series capacitors. Both the top and bottom circuits are identical, and if more capacitor arrays need to be added, this circuitry will simply be copied.

This type of balancer cannot work by supplying with voltage source (V1). It has to be supplied with current source.
So place a limiting resistor with with V1 at least. Or build a transistor current source instead od V1.
Btw, this balancer is very poor designed regarding thermal dependence/stability. The caps voltage can fluctuate roughly about 1.3-1.7V during -20-+40degC ambient temperature change and components heating.
Edit: (How balancer works)
When both caps are empty or bit discharged and you connect the circuit to current source the balancer circuit is inactive (you can neglect it).
Once one of cap reaches its limit (given by diodes drops) its transistor become conducting a start to carry a current instead of cap, so cap voltage will stay at its limit (1V5 or so) even the power supplies remains pluged.
Another words , the energy does not flow to cap now but it is waisted on transistor.
Edit2:
Much precise cap voltage you will get by using 1.25V refference like TLV431.
The cap voltage is set by R1:R2 ratio. A 2955 pnp transistor can be used also if BD136 is not available.


Do you mean I should use a current source instead of V1, like 10 A for the simulation? After adding the 10 A current source, the voltage around C6 and C5 is the same, but I still cannot analyze or understand how the circuit works and how much voltage will be applied for charging C6 and C5. Any advice? Thanks.

@ Michal Podmanicky Can you also explain why you mentioned 'build a transistor current source'? I was under the impression that simply dividing the voltage across the capacitor array would create a supercapacitor charger.

A charging current is given by current source. If you use 10A current source the caps will be charged with 10A. There is no another limitation of current in this circuit until caps reached 1V5. Then the current become limited.

How do you want to divide 6V into two 1V5 caps? There is remainded 3V from power supply, not? This 3V remainder has to be dropped on resistor in series with 6V source as I mentioned.

@  Michal Podmanický : Got it, thanks. However, I’m having trouble understanding how this circuit is supposed to balance the capacitors when they have different tolerances. For example, if one has a voltage rating of 2.7V and another has a rating of 2.5V, how does it maintain balance?

I added the functional description to my answear. The cap max voltage is set by diodes drop, so by changing this drops (add diodes or even change them to leds or tl431) you can set the cap max voltage.

@ Michal Podmanický: Thank you. For now, I’ve observed that when there is no charge, the circuit remains inactive. During the capacitor charging process, the transistor is off. Once the capacitor is fully charged, the transistor turns on and starts passing current.

@ Michal Podmanický: However, how can I ensure that the transistor stays off during the charging process? The values don’t seem to add up. For instance, if I(V1) = (V1 - VTLV) / 10k + (V1 - VTLV) / 220, V1 would be greater than VTLV, causing the transistor to turn on. Could you please provide some calculations for one of these states?
Thank you.
